# Bash script behaves differently when run by Apache and when run manually by www-data: why?

Tags: bash, apache-httpd

I have a test script below which attempts to carry out some filesystem maintenance. This is just a simple fragment; it unmounts an LVM logical volume (mounted at `/data`), and runs `e2fsck` on the device. The script has to be run remotely, via Apache.

**The problem is that the script works when I log into the remote and run it manually as user `www-data`, but it doesn't work when Apache runs it**. When Apache runs it, the script thinks that it has successfully unmounted `/data`, but `e2fsck` then fails because it thinks the device is still busy. However, a test with `fuser` doesn't show anything, and the device is still mounted when the script terminates.

I run it manually as follows:

```
root@vserver # su www-data -s /bin/bash
www-data@vserver $ cfg-test.sh
Status: 200 OK
Content-type: text/html

<p>Completed Ok.</p>
```

On completion, the state of the remote system is as expected: `/data` is unmounted, and the syslog contains:

```
Jan 23 15:51:26 vserver cfg-test.sh: Restarting as root
Jan 23 15:51:26 vserver cfg-test.sh: Unmounting /data...
Jan 23 15:51:27 vserver cfg-test.sh: Unmount succeeded; ll /data: (total 0)
Jan 23 15:51:27 vserver cfg-test.sh: e2fsck Ok
```

This is exactly what I'm expecting. I can instead run this over the web by browsing to `https://vserver/cfg-test.sh`. However, this doesn't work; the browser reports `Terminated with code 3. See the syslog for details.` The syslog shows:

```
Jan 23 15:48:49 vserver cfg-test.sh: Restarting as root
Jan 23 15:48:49 vserver cfg-test.sh: Unmounting /data...
Jan 23 15:48:49 vserver cfg-test.sh: Unmount succeeded; ll /data: (total 0)
Jan 23 15:48:49 vserver cfg-test.sh: fuser -c /dev/mapper/vg0-data: ()
Jan 23 15:48:49 vserver cfg-test.sh: e2fsck failed; terminating (/dev/mapper/vg0-data is in use.#012e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.) (/dev/mapper/vg0-data)
```

However, the `umount` did *not* succeed; `/data` is still mounted on the remote server. Why is this result different from a manual run of the script? The remote is a Ubuntu 22.04 VM, if it's relevant. The script is in the `sudoers` file to allow it to be run by `www-data` without a password.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

scriptname=$(basename "$0")
dev=/dev/mapper/vg0-data

retcode=0

# log messages to syslog
log() {
    if (($# < 1)); then
        return
    fi

    msg="$1"
    shift
    while (($# > 0))
    do
        msg+=" ($1)"
        shift
    done
    logger -t "$scriptname" "$msg"
}

if ((EUID > 0)); then
    log "Restarting as root"
    exec sudo "$0" "$@"

fi

while true ; do
    log "Unmounting /data..."
    output=$(umount -vvv --force /data 2>&1)
    code=$?
    if ((code > 0)); then
        log "umount /data failed; terminating" "$code" "$output"
        log "ll /data:" "$(ls -l /data)"
        retcode=1
        break
    fi

    # check mount's output
    if output=$(mount | grep "$dev" 2>&1); then
        log "/data is still mounted!" "$output"
        log "ll /data:" "$(ls -l /data)"
        retcode=2
        break
    fi


    # exit codes 0 and 1 are both Ok
    log "Unmount succeeded; ll /data:" "$(ls -l /data)"
    output=$(e2fsck -p -f "$dev" 2>&1)
    if (($? > 1)); then
        log "fuser -c $dev:" "$(fuser -c $dev)"
        log "e2fsck failed; terminating" "$output" "$dev"
        retcode=3
        break
    fi

    log "e2fsck Ok"
    break
done

if ((retcode == 0)); then
    echo "Status: 200 OK"
    echo "Content-type: text/html"
    echo ""
    echo "<p>Completed Ok.</p>"
else
    echo "Status: 400 Bad Request"
    echo "Content-type: text/html"
    echo ""
    echo "<p>Terminated with code $retcode. See the syslog for details.</p>"
fi
```

Comment: Does `/data` actually live at `/dev/mapper/vg0-data`?

Comment: @eyoung100: yes, it does: `df -h` shows `/dev/mapper/vg0-data   90M  132K   83M   1% /data`. I only use `/data` explicitly in the script because the directory name is preferred for `umount`.

Comment: And what happens when you run the script manually pointing it at the same location? I.e.  try `su www-data && umount /dev/mapper/vg0-data` and report back.  We want to see if the command succeeds outside of the script to see if the command has issues or the script

Comment: Umm... don't think I can run that as a one-liner? I just get 'This account is currently not available'

Comment: Try as root...  If the www-data user doesn't exist why are you su'ing to that user?

Comment: @eyoung100: if I run as root, I can `umount /dev/mapper/vg0-data`, and the contents of `/data` disappear, as expected; I can then `mount /dev/mapper/vg0-data` to reverse this. User `www-data` does exist and is the Apache user. However, it's a system user with no password, so I can't add it to the sudo group. I'm not sure about the error message from your suggested one-liner: either `umount` is not run as `www-data`, or `www-data` isn't allowed to run to run `umount`, presumably.

Comment: another datapoint: `cfg-test.sh` is in the sudoers file for both myself and `www-data`. When I run it as myself it succeeds, and `/data` is unmounted, as expected. Exactly the same happens when I run the script as user `www-data`. The only time this doesn't happen is when Apache runs the script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151046/discussion-between-eyoung100-and-eml).

Comment: It's very dangerous what you're doing there.